# Parse iOS beginner: getting an exception on PFUser signup

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am fairly new to both iOS development and Parse. I am going through the parse documentation and trying to build a proof of concept app that would be relevant to my project.  https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-props/iOS

The following code is directly from the guide:

```
- (void)myMethod {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user.username = @"my name";
    user.password = @"my pass";
    user.email = @"email@example.com";

    // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
    [user setObject:@"415-392-0202" forKey:@"phone"];

    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
      } else {
          NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
          // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
      }
    }];
}
```

I have integrated this method into my app and running it throws the following exception:

```
-[PFObject setIsCurrentUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b63be0
2013-07-02 21:50:00.147 signuptest[58478:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject setIsCurrentUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b63be0
```

I am hoping that someone who has more familiarity with Parse can point me towards the right direction here.  I have dug through the api and I do not see the setIsCurrentUser: method anywhere for PFObject.

My end goal is to basically create the PFUser object and save it on Parse database using the above method. 
Does anyone know why that exception is being thrown?  I can provide the full code of my test app if needed.

Comment: Try to place exception breakpoint to see on which particular line the exception is thrown.

Comment: I don't see setIsCurrentUser: in this example. Are you using that elsewhere in your app?

Comment: No, like I said in the question.  There is no method setIsCurrentUser.  The exception is being thrown on the server side.  So I am guessing it is one of the internal methods. I can't find this method in Parse api docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the problem was.  Previously in  the same project I had subclassed the `PFUser` object using `MyUser` object class and had registered that subclass with parse.  Later on I deleted the subclass and reverted back to the original `PFUser` object for my app. However XCode had cached the previous build configs and continued to use them.  Therefore I was getting an instance mismatch on the server.  The method itself works fine.

The solution: 
Cleared out the caches and any old build files using this as a reference: 
[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

I hope this will help anyone who has the same problem in the future.